# Android Studio does not recognize android annotations and shows errors in standard libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed latest Android Studio and generated hello world project (using Java) with empty activity. It builds just fine. But when I navigate to the file from standard android library `Activity.java` (using Ctrl+Click) it's full of errors. Similar thing happens with other standard android classes. And it's not only aesthetic issue. It seems that `android.annotation.Nullable` is ignored by IDE. For example I can write `getActionBar().hashCode()` in my Java code and it does not produce any warnings, despite the fact that method getActionBar() is annotated with `android.annotation.Nullable`. If I would write `getSupportActionBar().hashCode()` it would be correctly highlighted with warning, because that method is defined in support library and uses `androidx.annotation.Nullable` which is recognized (support library files seem to work fine, it's only "core" android library files affected by this issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.annotaion.Nullable` is a newly added Android annotation. You'll see it red because it's not publically available, it's restricted to Android AOSP use only.

If you want to use `Nullable` annotation, you'll have to use the `androidx.annotation.Nullable` ones.

`android.annotaion.Nullable` is Android (AOSP) code, while `androidx.annotation.Nullable` is Jetpack code, it's a Library (first party).